# Heap not getting free in C

Tags: c, struct, heap-memory, dynamic-memory-allocation

This is my code snippet, I'm getting error while I'm trying to free the allocated memory.

```
int main()
{
    int value = 10; 
    totValues = pow(2, value);
    head = (node_t *)calloc(totValues, sizeof(node_t));
    createNode(head, 10, 20);
    free(head);
}

void createList(node_t *head, int tag, int index)
{
      node_t temp = (node_t) calloc(1, sizeof(sizeof(node_t)));
      temp->tag = tag;
      temp->next = head[index];
      head[index] = temp;
      free(temp);
 }
```

I'm trying to free both head and temp node, but this is not working and I see errors. I'm tracing memory leaks using valgrind. Not sure what wrong I'm doing.

Comment: For one thing, although you have not shown `totValues` I suspect `calloc(sizeof(totValues), sizeof(node_t));` should be `calloc(totValues, sizeof(node_t));`

Comment: Why are you doing `sizeof(sizeof(node_t))`? Doubling the `sizeof` operator is not what you want.

Comment: I corrected that, but still heap is occupied

Comment: You shouldn't free `temp`, since you put it into the list with `head[index] = temp;`.

Comment: Why do you allocate memory, populate it with useful information, and then free it?! What purpose does that serve?

Comment: even if I don't free temp, head is still allocated..

Comment: Yes, but it contains a pointer to nothing.

Comment: I finished the operation what I wanted to do, I no more need the heap memory right? we should explicitly free dynamically allocated memory right?

Comment: `sizeof(sizeof(node_t))` is not correct. It's only allocating enough space for a single `int`, so you're writing outside the bounds when you do `temp->next = head[index];`

Comment: `temp->next = head[index];` should probably be `temp->next = &head[index];`.

Comment: Also `node_t temp = (node_t) calloc(...)` should be a pointer (ie. `node_t* temp = (node_t*)calloc(...)`).

Comment: @rampuriyaaa The operation was to create a list. When you're finished creating the list, you're not finished with the list! You can't go freeing parts of it until you're done with the list.

Comment: Another thing, you want `head` to be a pointer to a bunch of nodes, right? Then `head` should probably be a `node_t**`, shouldn't it?

Comment: `temp` and `head` are not nodes, they are variables that contain addresses of nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues you have in your example. Here is a look at your code with some fixes:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {
    int tag;
    struct node* next;
} node_t;

void createList(node_t**, int, int);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int value = 10; 
    int totValues = (int)pow(2, value);
    // `head` is an array of `node_t` pointers
    // (aka. it is a `node_t**` not a `node_t*`)
    node_t** head = (node_t**)calloc(totValues, sizeof(node_t*));
    createList(head, 10, 20);
    free(head);
    return 0;
}

void createList(node_t **head, int tag, int index)
{
    // You don't want `sizeof(sizeof(node_t))` because that is
    // equivalent to sizeof(size_t) which is implementation defined,
    // but usually equal to 4 or 8 depending on word size.
    node_t* temp = (node_t*)calloc(1, sizeof(node_t));
    temp->tag = tag;
    temp->next = head[index];
    head[index] = temp;
    // You fill `temp` with information, point a spot in `head` to
    // that pointer and then free the memory...
    // That makes no sense. Don't do it!
    free(temp);
}
```

It is important to remember that `free` doesn't recursively free memory for a double pointer: you will need to do that yourself.

You should call `free` on each node in `head` and then on `head` itself:

```
createList(head, 10, 20);
free(head[20]); //Free the one node we created
free(head); // Free the array of nodes we created
```

and make sure you comment out or remove the `free(temp);` call in the `createList` function.

When you run valgrind on this, there are no more memory leaks.

```
==6322== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==6322== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==6322== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==6322== Command: ./dynamic_memory
==6322== 
==6322== 
==6322== HEAP SUMMARY:
==6322==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6322==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 2 frees, 8,208 bytes allocated
==6322== 
==6322== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==6322== 
==6322== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==6322== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```